# Android ActionBar not showing for AppCompat v7 on API 8

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-menu, android-actionbar-compat

I'm trying to display the `ActionBar` on my API 8 emulator by using the `v7 AppCompat` library, But it's not showing. Even the Split Action Bar does not show. The user has to click the menu button to show the options. I need 4 of the options to always be visible on my screen.

**EDIT:**:

I have `android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"`, in case it helps...

Here is my menu xml code:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:symagine="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_twitter"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_twitter_icon"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    symagine:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/twitter_desc"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_share"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_share"
    android:orderInCategory="5"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    symagine:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/share_desc"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_rightDrawer"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_i"
    android:orderInCategory="6"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    symagine:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/action_info"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_facebook"
    android:icon="@drawable/facebook_icon"
    android:orderInCategory="2"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    symagine:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/facebook_desc"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_contact"
    android:orderInCategory="3"
    android:showAsAction="collapseActionView"
    symagine:showAsAction="collapseActionView"
    android:title="@string/action_contact"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/about_us"
    android:orderInCategory="4"
    android:showAsAction="collapseActionView"
    symagine:showAsAction="collapseActionView"
    android:title="@string/action_about_us"/>

</menu>
```

Here is my HomeActivity Code:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
    return true;
}
```

My custom action bar theme:

```
<style name="MyActionBarTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay" tools:ignore="NewApi">true</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle" tools:ignore="NewApi">@style/MyCustomActionBar</item>

    <!-- Support Library Compatibility -->
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyCustomActionBar</item>
</style>
<style name="MyCustomActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundSplit" tools:ignore="NewApi">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:logo" tools:ignore="NewApi">@drawable/ic_logo</item>
    <item name="android:displayOptions" tools:ignore="NewApi">showHome|useLogo</item>

    <!-- Support Library Compatibility -->
    <item name="background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="backgroundSplit">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="logo">@drawable/ic_logo</item>
    <item name="displayOptions">showHome|useLogo</item>
</style>
```

Please can anyone tell me what's the problem? I looked at some previous questions and saw that you need to add `[yourapp]` namespace in `showAsAciton`. I did that but it still didnt make a difference. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Remove from menu xml every line with "android:showAsAction="xxx""

Comment: yeah but if i do that, the menu won't even show on my phone which is running android 4.2.1

Comment: It should be shown, because symagine:showAsAction using for backward compatibility. You can create new android project with NavigationDrawer in Android studio and take a look how it works :)

Comment: Im using eclipse and it shows if i type both.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

guys! I found the solution. Apparently I wasn't extending `ActionBarActivity` so the `ActionBar` wasn't showing on devices less than Android 3.0.

Just thought you guys should know. I was earlier extending `FragmentActivity` and thought that if I changed it to `ActionBarActivity`, my Fragments which were running would not work...

But, it turns out that `ActionBarActivity` extends `FragmentActivity` so you needn't worry of the fact that one or the other might not work. Hope this helps someone out there!

`Merry Christmas!!`

Comment: Please set this as the answer.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use a support library like actionbarsherlock. I think [this tutorial](http://www.grokkingandroid.com/adding-actionbarsherlock-to-your-project/) will help you.